# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can both monsters in Tokyo yield at the same time after an attack?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/can-both-monsters-in-tokyo-yield-at-the-same-time-after-an-attack)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is needed to play X-wing with 4 players?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12738/what-is-needed-to-play-x-wing-with-4-players)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Countering the enchanting of a creature](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12885/countering-the-enchanting-of-a-creature)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Do the Saar need to wait a whole round to build a Space Dock?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12742/do-the-saar-need-to-wait-a-whole-round-to-build-a-space-dock)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Properly choosing a random discard](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/properly-choosing-a-random-discard)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Removing to Reapply Decals](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/removing-to-reapply-decals)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is it possible to have more than one active artifact in Redemption?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-active-artifact-in-redemption)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Do I need to buy data packs to be competitive?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/do-i-need-to-buy-data-packs-to-be-competitive)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Choose from discard pile ability: put into play simultaneously?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12961/choose-from-discard-pile-ability-put-into-play-simultaneously)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [In bridge, if a 1 NT bidder is doubled, is it right to "redouble for rescue?"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12898/in-bridge-if-a-1-nt-bidder-is-doubled-is-it-right-to-redouble-for-rescue)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

Comment: I thought these questions were a lot better than last time, but the scoring doesn't agree with me! Does anyone have suggestions for how they would like to see us improve? (or maybe the difference in scores isn't significant?)

Comment: One of my questions got -1... argh.

Comment: @BlakBat I think the question's fine, it's just the only answer we've collectively come up with doesn't really give you the help you wanted.

Comment: @tttppp, "Do the Saar need to wait a whole round to build a Space Dock?" **This one looks potentially incorrect.** Do I need to buy data packs to be competitive? **This one has a title/body mismatch, competitive vs chance to win.** I personally put little weight in these evaluations. There is an issue with comparing the Q&As on the whole. How do you score a good question with a poor answer or visa versa? How do you rate one with a correct answer, but an incorrect answer equally Upvoted (down by 1, 3, 5)?